# !Argument of \MT@gobble@to@nil has an extra }

Tags: texlive, templates, compilation-error, microtype, latex-workshop

This is my first ever StackExchange question - please be gentle :) I have experience using Latex online on Overleaf but never locally, so I am completely new to this.

I am trying to use my university's dissertation Latex template which can be found on this github link: https://github.com/DigiUGA/UGA-Dissertation-LaTeX-Template and it works just fine on Overleaf. However, I would like to work on it from my personal computer (for peace of mind and to track it with git). I'm using VScode, with the Latex Workshop extension by James Yu, and a tex live installation. Building the project on vscode fails with this error: `"pdflatex: Command for 'pdflatex' gave return code 1".`

Naturally, I opened up the Tex Live commandline and ran the command "pdlatex dissertation.tex" which returns this error `"!Argument of \MT@gobble@to@nil has an extra }".`

[image: Tex Live console error]

As seen in the image above, in addition to what I assume is the error message, there were some warnings from the microtype package. So I followed the recommendation and disabled the spacing option in the file metafiles/structure.tex line 28 so that it reads as follows:

```
%Word spacing and letter spacing
\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},final,tracking=true,kerning=true,spacing=false,factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=10]{microtype}
```

which cleared the warnings, but the error remains and the pdflatex command fails to output a pdf file.

Interestingly, although the VScode compilation fails with errors, it outputs a pdf that contains everything except the table of contents, the list of figures, and the list of tables which are all blank. When I open dissertation.tex on VScode, there's a red squiggly line under line 38, which indicates that there is an error in the code, as shown in the image below:
[image: vscode indicates there's an error on line 38 after the \makeabstract command]

Hovering over this line pulls up VScode's debug information, and it seems like @MT@gobble@to@nil and \MT@prot@getfirstgrouptc might be causing the issue and it's something in the abstractpage.tex file, located at metafiles/abstractpage.tex.
[image: Hovering over the error pulls up some debug information]

Opening abstractpage.tex shows that, indeed, it contains the commands to create a group (\begingroup and \endgroup). Highly suspicious that the issue was in the abstract, I commented out the \makeabstract portion in dissertation.tex as shown in the image below (lines : 36-38):

[image: commenting out the \makeabstract command in dissertation.tex]

And the project compiles fine with no errors (both on VScode and on Tex Live command prompt) but the abstract is absent.

I used the search function to try and find the location of either @MT@gobble@to@nil or \MT@prot@getfirstgrouptc in the project, but nothing came up, so I'm assuming they are nestled somewhere among the files in the Tex Live installation.

What could be the issue here and how would I fix it? I'm playing around with the abstractpage.tex file at the moment to see if I can narrow down the issue. I've disabled the  \group and \endgroup but that does not fix it. Thank you in advance!

(PS: my setup compiles a barebones  IEEE conference template just fine)

UPDATE: I narrowed down the error to these three lines of code in abstractpage.tex:

```
  \textsc{\Large{\doctitle}}\\[18pt]
  by\\[18pt]
  \textsc{\Large\docauthor}\\[12pt]
```

and replacing them with the following lines allows for successful compilation:

```
\doctitle\\
by\\
\docauthor\\
```

Then the strangest thing happened: intending to narrow it down further by changing each line out, I ended up with almost the same code as before and it works! I'm scratching my head as to why this would work:

```
\newcommand{\makeabstract}[1]{
\begingroup
\newpage

\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{18pt}
\begin{center}

    % \doctitle\\
    % by\\
    % \docauthor\\
  \textsc{\Large{\doctitle}}\\[18pt]
  by\\[18pt]
  \textsc{\Large\docauthor}\\[12pt]
  (Under the Direction of [Prof's Name] (No Dr. or PhD))\\[12pt]
  \textsc{Abstract}
\end{center}

#1

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{list}{\textsc{Index words:\hfill}}{\labelwidth 1.2in\leftmargin 1.4in\labelsep 0.2in}
  \item \begin{flushleft}
    [PUT YOUR LIST OF INDEX WORDS HERE SEPERATED BY COMMAS]
  \end{flushleft}
\end{list}
\endgroup
}
```

But this doesn't work:

```
\newcommand{\makeabstract}[1]{
\begingroup
\newpage

\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{18pt}
\begin{center}
  \textsc{\Large{\doctitle}}\\[18pt]
  by\\[18pt]
  \textsc{\Large\docauthor}\\[12pt]
  (Under the Direction of [Prof's Name] (No Dr. or PhD))\\[12pt]
  \textsc{Abstract}
\end{center}

#1

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{list}{\textsc{Index words:\hfill}}{\labelwidth 1.2in\leftmargin 1.4in\labelsep 0.2in}
  \item \begin{flushleft}
    [PUT YOUR LIST OF INDEX WORDS HERE SEPERATED BY COMMAS]
  \end{flushleft}
\end{list}
\endgroup}
```

Second update:
okay, so apparently there needs to be an empty line between these two lines?

```
\begin{center}
  
  \textsc{\Large{\doctitle}}\\[18pt]
```

and if there isn't, the compiler (or something else) adds a \par? Hopefully, someone with more experience could shed some light on this.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  If you are reporting errors or sharing code, it's much easier for us if you copy and paste that information into your question.  (I have difficulty reading the images, and others may too; in any event, if testing is called for, no one will wast to retype it.)  Regarding a possible missing brace, one easy check is to count the number of opening braces in the abstract and, separately, the closing braces.  The counts should be equal.  If they're not, you'll know what to look for.

Comment: Thank you for the welcome and the reply. That's a good point about posting code instead of images. I wasn't sure what was causing the error, that's why I provided the GitHub link with the whole project.

Comment: Try to post a complete, self-contained example people can compile to reproduce the problem. Right now, for example, nobody can compile the code you've pasted. (And not many will be willing to deal with your entire project.) Off-topic: `\Large` doesn't take an argument. `\Large{abc} rest of document` is the same as `\Large abc rest of document`.

Comment: If I minimally complete your code, I don't get an error. It compiles fine.

Comment: @cfr thanks for completing my code and trying it. I was completely lost as to what the issue was and, as it turns out from the answer below, it lies within the microtype package. So, to provide a self-contained example, I  needed to have known that ,and included it within the example document. And I do agree with you that a complete self-contained example is ideal, and aids in finding the solution - I'll strive to do that in future.

Comment: this has been fixed in `microtype` v3.1b

Answer (score 5, accepted):

microtype patches the `\item` command to implement protrusion for the begin of the item body. This patch looks ahead at the following command. Sadly this often leads to errors if the text after the `\item` begins with some command.

`center` is internally implemented as a list with one element and it starts the text with `item` and this here errors:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}

\newcommand\doctitle{abc}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \textsc{\Large{\doctitle}}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Work-arounds are

- disable the patch

```
\microtypesetup{nopatch=item}
```

- interrupt e.g. with a brace pair, or as you found out with an empty line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}

\newcommand\doctitle{abc}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  {}\textsc{\Large{\doctitle}}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and explanation! Both setting ```nopatch=item``` and including the curly braces allow for successful compilation.